# Guzzle async requests not really async?

Tags: php, guzzle6

## Problem

We are trying to do concurrent asynchronous requests using guzzle. After going through a few resources, like [this](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/1127) and [this](https://blog.madewithlove.be/post/concurrent-http-requests/), we came up with some code that is shared below. However it is not working as expected.

It looks like Guzzle is doing these requests synchronously rather than async.

## Expectation

Just for test purposes, we are hitting an internal url, which does a 5 second sleep. With a concurrency of 10 we expect that all 10 requests will initially be queued and sent to the server *almost* simultaneously, where they will wait for 5 seconds, and then *almost* all of those will finish nearly at the same time, which would make the guzzle client to pick up 10 new requests from iterator and so on.

### Code

```
    $iterator = function() {
        $index = 0;
        while (true) {
            $client = new Client(['timeout'=>20]);
            $url = 'http://localhost/wait/5' . $index++;
            $request = new Request('GET',$url, []);
            echo "Queuing $url @ " . (new Carbon())->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . PHP_EOL;
            yield $client
                ->sendAsync($request)
                ->then(function(Response $response) use ($request) {
                    return [$request, $response];
                });
        }
    };

    $promise = \GuzzleHttp\Promise\each_limit(
        $iterator(),
        10,  /// concurrency,
        function($result, $index) {
            /** GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request $request */
            list($request, $response) = $result;
            echo (string) $request->getUri() . ' completed '.PHP_EOL;
        },
        function(RequestException $reason, $index) {
            // left empty for brevity
        }
    );
    $promise->wait();
```

## Actual Results

We find that that Guzzle never made a second request until the first one is finished. and so on.

```
Queuing http://localhost/wait/5/1 @ 2017-09-01 17:15:28
Queuing http://localhost/wait/5/2 @ 2017-09-01 17:15:28
Queuing http://localhost/wait/5/3 @ 2017-09-01 17:15:28
Queuing http://localhost/wait/5/4 @ 2017-09-01 17:15:28
Queuing http://localhost/wait/5/5 @ 2017-09-01 17:15:28
Queuing http://localhost/wait/5/6 @ 2017-09-01 17:15:28
Queuing http://localhost/wait/5/7 @ 2017-09-01 17:15:28
Queuing http://localhost/wait/5/8 @ 2017-09-01 17:15:28
Queuing http://localhost/wait/5/9 @ 2017-09-01 17:15:28
Queuing http://localhost/wait/5/10 @ 2017-09-01 17:15:28
http://localhost/wait/5/1 completed
Queuing http://localhost/wait/5/11 @ 2017-09-01 17:15:34
http://localhost/wait/5/2 completed
Queuing http://localhost/wait/5/12 @ 2017-09-01 17:15:39
http://localhost/wait/5/3 completed
Queuing http://localhost/wait/5/13 @ 2017-09-01 17:15:45
http://localhost/wait/5/4 completed
Queuing http://localhost/wait/5/14 @ 2017-09-01 17:15:50
```

OS / Version information

- Ubuntu
- PHP/7.1.3
- GuzzleHttp/6.2.1
- curl/7.47.0

The issue could be with \GuzzleHttp\Promise\each_limit .. which perhaps does not initiates or resolves the promise fast enough. It may be possible that we have to trick that into `tick`ing externally.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In the example code, you're creating a new `GuzzleHttp\Client` instance for every request you want to make. This might not seem important, however, during instantiation of `GuzzleHttp\Client` it will set a default [handler](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/Client.php#L64) if none is provided. (This value is then passed down to any request being sent through the Client, unless it is overridden.)

Note: It determines the best handler to use from [this](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/functions.php#L103) function. Though, it'll most likely end up defaulting to `curl_multi_exec`.

What's the importance of this? It's the underlying handler that is responsible for tracking and executing multiple requests at the same time. By creating a new handler every time, none of your requests are properly being grouped up and ran together. For some more insight into this take a gander into the [`curl_multi_exec` docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php).

So, you kind of have two ways of dealing with this:

Pass through the client through to the iterator:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['timeout' => 20]);

$iterator = function () use ($client) {
    $index = 0;
    while (true) {
        if ($index === 10) {
            break;
        }

        $url = 'http://localhost/wait/5/' . $index++;
        $request = new Request('GET', $url, []);
        
        echo "Queuing $url @ " . (new Carbon())->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . PHP_EOL;
        
        yield $client
            ->sendAsync($request)
            ->then(function (Response $response) use ($request) {
                return [$request, $response];
            });

    }
};

$promise = \GuzzleHttp\Promise\each_limit(
    $iterator(),
    10,  /// concurrency,
    function ($result, $index) {
        /** @var GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request $request */
        list($request, $response) = $result;
        echo (string)$request->getUri() . ' completed ' . PHP_EOL;
    }
);
$promise->wait();
```

or create the handler elsewhere and pass it to the client: (Though I'm not sure why you'd do this, but it's there!)

```
$handler = \GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack::create();

$iterator = function () use ($handler) {
    $index = 0;
    while (true) {
        if ($index === 10) {
            break;
        }

        $client = new Client(['timeout' => 20, 'handler' => $handler])
        $url = 'http://localhost/wait/5/' . $index++;
        $request = new Request('GET', $url, []);

        echo "Queuing $url @ " . (new Carbon())->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . PHP_EOL;

        yield $client
            ->sendAsync($request)
            ->then(function (Response $response) use ($request) {
                return [$request, $response];
            });

    }
};

$promise = \GuzzleHttp\Promise\each_limit(
    $iterator(),
    10,  /// concurrency,
    function ($result, $index) {
        /** @var GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request $request */
        list($request, $response) = $result;
        echo (string)$request->getUri() . ' completed ' . PHP_EOL;
    }
);
$promise->wait();
```

Comment: The reason creating a new client is important is because requirements dictate the use of proxy server and other request specific parameters. Meaning that, every request may be a completely different request, including url, header and method.
If I create a single client instance, I do not know what it will share with other requests. With that logic, probably the second solution you proposed is preferable. I will try both of the solutions proposed above and report back. Too bad I am at home right now .. and don't have the setup to try the above.

Comment: You should be able to set that on your request with the `proxy` option, http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#proxy.

Comment: *By creating a new handler every time, none of your requests are properly being grouped up* **Why is this a problem?** Why can't they run together in separate groups? Does that mean that if I'm making only one request, it'll always be run synchronously?

Comment: I got here to find out that in order to run async, php-curl is a must. I didn't had it installed and I spent 2 days trying to  find the problem.

Comment: Thanks for that answer @AdamLavin. I think I need this too for my case. I just wonder if I can even use it: I have built a proxy server, and whenever a request hits it it just forwards the request to a REST API (adds credentials) and passes back the response.
Now locally my server crashes if I have too many requests at the same time, so I would have to use promises, I assume.
But the difference is, that whenever I executed my php code where I create Clients and requests, they don't know if there are other requests around... so how would you tackle that problem?

Comment: Maybe this even relates to @Scalable s comment, but I am too inexperienced to really make sense of all that...

Comment: @AdamLavin providing links to specific files (and even lines!) in master branch is not a good idea - it is almost certainly guaranteed that they'll become outdated as time goes by. a better option is to use revision hash instead of branch name

Comment: So this is useless because you now have to thread a `Client` instance through your whole app to make it work 

Comment: Check PHP 8.1 -  Fibers to support async