# Handle multiple guzzle request in proxy for REST API (local server crashes)

Tags: rest, proxy, guzzle, guzzle6

I have the following case: I have a REST API, that can only be accessed with credentials. I need the frontend to make requests directly to the API to get the data. Because I don't want to *hide* the credentials somewhere in the frontend, I set up a proxy server, which forwards my request with http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/index.html but adds the necessary authentication.

No that worked neatly for some time, but now I added a new view where I need to fetch from one more endpoint. (so far it was 3 requests locally (MAMP))

Whenever I add a fourth API request, which all are being executed right on page load, my local server crashes.

I assume it is linked to this topic here:
[Guzzle async requests not really async?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46015529/guzzle-async-requests-not-really-async/46019201#46019201), specifically because I make a new request for every fetch.

First: Do you think that could be the case? Could my local server indeed crash, because I have only 3 (probably simultaneous) requests?

Second: How could I approach this problem.
I don't really see the possibility to group the requests, because they are just incoming to the proxy url and every call of the proxy url will create a new Guzzle client with its own request...

(I mean, how many things can a simple PHP server execute at the same time? And why would it not just add requests to the call stack and execute them in order?)

Thanks for any help on this issue.